# How to dynamically add dojox.mobile.ListItem to a RoundRectList?

Tags: cordova, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to dynamically add `dojox.mobile.ListItem`s into a `dojox.mobile.RoundRectList` and am struggling with something that should be relatively simple.

This is my dojo widget :

```
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList" id="theTable" >
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            data-dojo-props='icon:"images/i-icon-1.png",
                            moveTo:"#article",
                            variableHeight:true' 
            id="theItem">
            text here
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I have a bit of javascript whereby I'm trying to grab a handle onto the `RoundRectList` and add some `ListItem`s into it :

```
dojo.require("dojox.mobile.parser");
dojo.require("dojox.mobile");
dojo.requireIf(!dojo.isWebKit, "dojox.mobile.compat");
var theTable = dojo.byId("theTable");
var childWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
                   id:"item1", 
                   icon:"images/icon.png", 
                   rightText:"Off", 
                   moveTo:"bar", 
                   label:"u1space"});
theTable.addChild(childWidget);
```

This doesn't appear to work, specifically displaying the following error in the Javascript console of Chrome :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addChild' of undefined

Can someone please advise me as to what I'm doing wrong here? Essentially, I have a JSON object that I'm trying to iterate over and put elements into a list.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To access dojo widgets you need to use dijit.byId NOT dojo.byId.  dojo.byId is used to access un-widgetized DOM nodes.  I have included an example below, but I would suggest looking into dojox.mobile.RoundRectDataList and not the plain dojox.mobile.RoundRectList.  The data list version is backed by a dojo.data.store and will allow dynamic updates much easier - http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/RoundRectDataList

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum- scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   require(["dojox/mobile/parser",
            "dijit/registry",
            "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
            "dojox/mobile",
            "dojo/domReady!"],function(parser,registry){
             parser.parse();
             var list = registry.byId("list");
             var childWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({id:"item1", 
                                                              icon:"images/icon.png", 
                                                              rightText:"Off", 
                                                              moveTo:"bar", 
                                                              label:"u1space"});
             list.addChild(childWidget);
           });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="settings" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" data-dojo-props="selected: true">

  <!-- a sample heading -->
  <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">Settings</h1>

  <!-- a rounded rectangle list container -->
  <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList" id="list">

     <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"article"' id="theItem">
        Go to Article view
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="article" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">

    <!-- a sample heading -->
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props='back: "settings",moveTo: "settings"'>Article</h1>

    This is the article view
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain precisely whether this is what is causing your problem, but you should probably use Dojo APIs (specifically, `dojo.place`) to place this ListItem inside the list rather than use JavaScript/DOM APIs. e.g.

```
dojo.place(childWidget.domNode, theTable)
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/place.html

Answer (score 0):

the error message seems to be saying that your theTable variable is not pointing to an object with an addChild() function - implying that dojo.byId() has failed.

I'd recommend checking what's in theTable first.

For comparison, I have working code doing the kind of thing you're trying to do, but I'm using a slightly different idiom:

I'm creating a Widget of my own, so I'm using an attachPoint - dapTaskList to get a handle to where I'm putting my list, and creating my list from scratch.

```
var ul  = new RoundRectList({}, domConstruct.create("ul",{}, this.dapTaskList) );
ul.startup();
```

I then add items with code like:

```
        li = new ListItem({
          "label"          : "xx",
          "rightText"      : 997, 
          "class"          : "subTotalListItem"
        }, domConstruct.create("li",{}, ul.domNode) );
        li.startup();
```